# Кроссдоменный AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, backend

Чем плохо то, что сервер разрешит всем производить кроссдоменный ajax? Будем обрабатывать эти запросы так же, как и от обычных клиентов и все дела. Что я упускаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тем, что подобная "всеразрешающая" политика:

- значительно снизит уровень безопасности в вебе;
- против интересов людей, которые в сети создают что-то помимо мусора.

---

Предположим, Вася пользуется популярным сайтом **А**, где у него есть учетная запись и некоторые персональные/чувствительные данные. 
И тут Вася открывает в другой вкладке браузера сайт **Б**, сделанный Петей.
Петя - сцуко хитрый. Он поместил на странице своего сайта скрипт, который обращается к сайту **А**. Если посетитель петиного сайта там авторизован,  Петя легко ворует чужие данные, а также может изменять и удалять их.
В реальном мире, что мешает таким Петям делать подобное? Политика same-origin!

Другой пример.
Иван запилил на своем сайте страницу, где регулярно выкладывает свои работы, интересные огромному числу посетителей. Сайт Ивана предоставляет оригинальный контент и работает быстро, посетители довольны.
И вдруг, Иван замечает что его сервер не справляется, посетители жалуются. Что еще хуже, в поисковике появился сайт Пети с копиями контента Ивана - и не просто с присвоением авторства, а еще и в окружении рекламы типа "порно-с-осликами-скачать-сейчас".
Посмотрев логи, Иван видит что его сервер  завален запросами от посетителей сайта Пети (потому что тот наговнокодил на jQuery парсер с интервалом выполнения 500мс).
В реальном мире, что помогает защищать контент <del>от тупых школьников с jQuery</del> и спасает от лишней нагрузки? Политика same-origin!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Уточнить хочу. Получается когда Вася зайдёт на сайт Б, по какой то причине выполнится скрипт и произойдёт переход на сайт А. Этот сайт вернёт данные Васи..но куда? Он же вернёт их Васе, а не Пете. Данные вернутся в браузер Васи, как к ним доступ можно получить?

Comment: @Semerkin, данные вернутся скрипту, который сможет с этими данными сделать все что угодно. Ну вот смотрите: одним запросом скрипт получает данные от сервера сайта А, вторым - отправляет эти данные серверу сайта Б (который, например, занесет их в базу данных. Или в ответе скрипту скомандует совершить какие-то действия - например, отправить рекламное сообщение другому юзеру сайта А). При этом, никаких переходов не выполняется, и пользователь вообще не заметит какой-либо передачи данных, если не будет шариться в веб-консоли.

Answer (score 1):

Если сервер разрешает `CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing)`, то появляется возможность использовать данные хранящиеся в браузере для доступа к личной информации пользователей.

Например в браузере хранится `Cookie` с сессией пользователя, тогда предоставляется возможность осуществлять действия от имени этого пользователя, отправляя запросы самостоятельно. Один из видов таких атак называется `CSRF`.

Существует много способов защиты от подобных атак, но в целях безопасности, многие сервера просто запрещают кроссдоменный доступ.

Comment: Не совсем понял... Как можно использовать данные в браузере? Браузером управляет все так же один и тот же клиент, как кросс ajax этому мешает то?